# How to import all url paths from urls.py and store it in a list in a view in views.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I want to store in a dict all the urls defined in main_urlpatterns within url.py:

```
main_urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', views.login_view, name='login')]
```

So in the view.py i created a function like follows:

```
from app_productora.urls import main_urlpatterns

def siteurls_view(request):

    url_list=main_urlpatterns


    context = {
        'url_list':url_list
    }
    return render(request, 'siteurls.html', context)
```

But i have a circular problem between the import of the views.py in url.py  and the import of the url.py in views.py.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried to google `python circular import` ? Or event search it on stackoverflow ?

Comment: Share the full error traceback.

Comment: hi sorry, Nicolas was right, is very simple. I have to do a plain import like "import app_productora.urls as urls" instead to " from app_productora.urls import main_url_patterns".